# Looping through ListObject

Tags: vba, datetime, listobject

I am having trouble looping through my tables using ListObjects.

I have a For loop nested in an If loop nested in a For Each loop. I am trying to add data to the tables based on the values in the adjacent columns. I have thrown in some Debug.print statements to determine if the entire nest works but I can't get the last For loop to operate. "Works2" will not print. VBA is showing data for all the variables and I am not getting any errors.

```
Public Sub StockDays()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim loc As Range
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim quarter, i, countrows As Integer

Set wb = Workbooks("DISTRIBUTOR REWORK DRAFT.xlsm")
Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
Set loc = ws.Range("A1:C50").Find("Days of Stock") 'I use this further in the program

countrows = ws.ListObjects(1).Range.Rows.count
quarter = DatePart("q", Date)

For Each tbl In ws.ListObjects
    Debug.Print "Works"
    If Mid(tbl.Name, 5, 1) = quarter Then
        For i = 2 To countrows
            Debug.Print "Works2"
            ws.ListObjects("DFCREDPAR").DataBodyRange.Cells(i, ws.ListObjects("DFCREDPAR").ListColumns("Days of Stock").Index) = ws.ListObjects("DFCREDPAR").Range.Cells(i, 2) / tbl.Range.Cells(i, 3)
        Next i
    End If
Next tbl

For Each tbl In ws.ListObjects: Debug.Print tbl.Name & vbTab & tbl.HeaderRowRange.Address & vbTab & tbl.DataBodyRange.Address: Next

End Sub
```

I've checked all the data types and believe them to all be correct (No Type Mismatches).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are the values of the variables involved in that loop? When you step through with F8 is the loop ever entered? If not, which condition is failing and why? Is If Mid(tbl.Name, 5, 1) = quarter  not working? Is countrows an unexpected value? .....

Comment: Hi QHaar, thank you for your input. Somehow I missed that they types were incompatible and the If loop was being skipped. Sometimes a fresh set of eyes is very helpful! Thank you!